# How to deliver hot water from bathroom to kitchen

Tags: pipe, boiler

My appartment (and all my neighbours as well) doesn't have hot water. So I recently purchased electric boiler (80L) and placed it in the bathroom. Now I'm planing to deliver the hot water from the bathroom to the kitchen. What kind of pipes I need? Do I need them insulated? I'm planning to run them near the floor.

I have very limited budget and I don't have any plumber friends that I can ask for advice.

I don't live in the US, if that helps :)

[image: a picture of how I'm imagining doing this]

Comment: Are they running entirely inside, or do they go outside at all? What is the temperature range of the ambient air? Are you trying to conceal the pipes in walls? Typically 3/4" copper or pex would be used, are either of those a problem?

Comment: You could put a small instant hot water heater in the kitchen instead. Cheap ones won't give a huge flow, but it will still be a nice upgrade from nothing.

Comment: Yes, the piping will be entirely inside and no, both are fine. Maybe in future I'd like to hide them beneath the floor or in wall, but not now. I'm not sure, but should be around 19-24 C. @JayBazuzi I have considered that, but Im more leaning towards the pipes, because that's way cheaper! :)

Comment: @r00m I'd recommend Jay's idea as well. A small, kitchen instahot runs about $200 on Amazon. By contrast, 1/2" copper costs about $2 per foot. After tools and fittings, 75 feet of run would make the instahot cheaper. PEX requires expensive tools, so you might be hiring someone. PEX also cannot be exposed to sunlight. Since you're outside the US, I can't predict shipping costs from Amazon or copper prices in your area, but all 3 options could be close. Maybe consider the instahot as instant water for tea/coffee, so it's an improvement.  ^_^